# MySQL table file names encoding

Tags: mysql, encoding, filenames

Could someone know what encoding is used here @T0@g0@x0@y0@w0@u0@p0@q0@o0.MYD ?

This is a file name corresponding to table name which name using cyrillic letters.

Answer (score 1):

This is the MySQL internal filename encoding [Documented here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-mapping.html).

You can convert this back to normal utf8 by using a procedure like:

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT(_filename'@T0@g0@x0@y0@w0@u0@p0@q0@o0' USING utf8);
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT(_filename'@T0@g0@x0@y0@w0@u0@p0@q0@o0' USING utf8) |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Настройки                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```